# using python 3 stacks to ensure symbols match in correct pairs and the types of symbols match as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, string-matching

```
def spc(sym):
    stk1=myStack()
    stkall=myStack()
    for i in sym:
        if i not in stk1:
            stk1.push(i)
        else:
            stkall.push(i)
    for j in stk1:
        for k in stkall:
            if j==k:
                stk1.pop(j)
                stkall.pop(k)
            else:
                pass
    if len(stk1) == len(stkall):
        print("all symbols match")
    else:
        print(("these symbols, %s,  have no matches")%(stkall))
```

Above code gives me this error
"TypeError: argument of type 'myStack' is not iterable"

But I fixed it by the answer from @SergeBallesta. After I edited code to look as you see now.

Now im getting this error:

"return self.container.pop(item)  # pop from the container, this was fixed from the old version which was wrong
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

What i want to achieve is for parenthesis and all symbols to be properly balanced in that not only does each opening symbol have a corresponding closing symbol, but the types of symbols match as well.

Code for my Stack class is below. Please assist to implement this using STACKS

```
class myStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.size() == 0
    def push(self, item):
        self.container.append(item
    def pop(self, item):
        return self.container.pop(item)
    def size(self):
        return len(self.container)  # length of the container

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)
```

Comment: You need to define `myStack.__iter__` to make your stacks iterables

Comment: `list.pop` accepts an optional index to pop from.  That index must be an integer.  You're trying to pop items by reference.  I doubt your `sym` is an iterable of integers.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  i called the function with a string of symbols .. the symbols are not integers.               
      spc('}{))[]({{}[][][]})})')

Answer (score 0):

These lines

```
if i not in stk1:
```

and

```
for j in stk1:
```

requires `myStack` to be *iterable*. In Python it means that it shall have an `__iter__` method that returns an *iterator* on its objects. As you already have an internal container, the `__iter__` method can be as simple as:

```
class myStack:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)
```

Comment: thanks @Serge, but i get another type error now;                           
         stk1.pop(j) and stkall.pop(k)

TypeError: pop() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given                    but I did passed one argument to pop()  ... i at one point and j at another point

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko The "one argument" is the instance of the stack, `self`.  It should be called `stack.pop()`.  A pure stack implementation should only be able to push, pop, and peek at the "top" elemnts

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I called pop on the stack objects (stk1 and stkall) which i created. Please explain exactly what you mean by it should be called stack.pop() . Can you do a demonstration please ?

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko: you declare 2 args for push (self, and item) and only pass item (which is correct). For `pop` you declare one single arg, so you shall pass none: `if j==k:
                stk1.pop() and stkall.pop()`

Comment: @SergeBallesta That works! Thanks. I fixed it. But here i get a new error             "return self.container.pop(item)  # pop from the container, this was fixed from the old version which was wrong

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"    Can you please help debug ?

Comment: @EwuramaMinkaAkuoko You're probably doing `stk.pop('1')`, when you should be doing `stk.pop(1)`.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh   please I have pasted the current code in the question above, I doubt I am pushing a string. Kindly check it for me. this is the exact error                                                                                                               
          "return self.container.pop(item)  # pop from the container, this was fixed from the old version which was wrong

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Answer (score 0):

To do bracket validation using a stack, we only need one stack.  As we come across opening brackets, we push them onto the stack.  When we come across a closing bracket, we pop the top opening bracket off the stack, and compare the two.  If they are the same bracket type, we continue, otherwise the string is invalid.  If we ever try to pop an empty stack, the string is invalid.  If we reach the end of the string without clearing the stack, the string is invalid.

```
opening = '[{<('
closing = ']}>)'

d = dict(zip(opening, closing))

def validate(s):
    stack = []
    for c in s:
        if c in opening:
            stack.append(c)
        elif c in closing:
            if not stack:
                # tried to pop empty stack
                return False
            popped = stack.pop()
            if d[popped] != c:
                # bracket mismatch
                return False
    return not stack
```