# In string of parenthesis validation program, how the push and pop operations of stack happens in each iteration

Tags: python

Here using a dictionary key as open brackets and value as closing bracket.how it actually works in stack?

```
 class py_solution:

    def is_valid_parenthese(self, str1):
        stack=[] 
        pchar = {"(": ")", "{": "}", "[": "]"}
        for parenthese in str1:
            if parenthese in pchar:
                 stack.append(parenthese)

            elif len(stack) == 0 or pchar[stack.pop()] != parenthese:


                return False
        return len(stack) == 0


st=raw_input("Enter string of parenthesis")
print(py_solution().is_valid_parenthese(st))
```

Comment: [Here's a similar piece of code I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441298/6779307) that has some explanation and slightly simpler structure.

Comment: In my question how the stack status in 'if' and 'elif' conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a parser for expressions is implemented using recursive functions, so instead of a loop (as in your or Patrick's example) a function will call itself or other functions recursively to parse the subexpressions, take their results and build a compound expression of the subexpressions.

Then the stack isn't handled explicitly by your code but the normal execution stack is used to achieve this.

Have a look at this implementation:

```
class Named_List(list):
  def __repr__(self):
    return '%s(%s)' % (type(self).__name__, ', '.join(repr(x) for x in self))

class Parens(Named_List): pass

class Brackets(Named_List): pass

class Braces(Named_List): pass

def parse(text):
  if not text:
    raise Exception("empty input")
  result = []
  if text[0] == '(':
    text = text[1:]
    while text[0] != ')':
      element, text = parse(text)
      result.append(element)
    return Parens(result), text[1:]
  elif text[0] == '[':
    text = text[1:]
    while text[0] != ']':
      element, text = parse(text)
      result.append(element)
    return Brackets(result), text[1:]
  elif text[0] == '{':
    text = text[1:]
    while text[0] != '}':
      element, text = parse(text)
      result.append(element)
    return Braces(result), text[1:]
  else:
    raise Exception("bad input", text)
```

This function returns an abstract syntax tree (AST) of the given parenthesis expression and the part it could not parse.  For an input like `'(((()[]{})))'` it will return `Parens(Parens(Parens(Parens(), Brackets(), Braces())))` (and the empty string because it could parse everything).  For a faulty input like `'(((()[]{)))'` it will raise an exception complaining about the bad rest `')))'` which wasn't parsable anymore.

Comment: Can you explain the functionalities with an example

Comment: when i call the function ,parse('{}')  lik this but nothing happens,can you say how can i call the function

Comment: There are two examples right below the source code.  The explanation is that after finding any opening paren, the function calls itself recursively to parse all the contents of the paren, then expects (and checks for) the matching closing paren.  When I call `parse('{}')` I get as a result: `(Braces(), '')` which means: There is one empty brace and an empty unparsed string left over.

Answer (score 0):

```
class py_solution:

    def is_valid_parenthese(self, str1):
        stack=[] 
        pchar = {"(": ")", "{": "}", "[": "]"}
        for parenthese in str1:
           if parenthese in pchar:
                 stack.append(parenthese)

           elif len(stack) == 0 or pchar[stack.pop()] != parenthese:


                return False
        return len(stack) == 0


st=raw_input("Enter string of parenthesis")
print(py_solution().is_valid_parenthese(st))
```

If the input is '{}' it pushes '{' to stack in the 'if' conditon after that the paranthesis is '{' which is not in the dictionary .so the item added to the list pop.Actually the value will be pop out.The poped value compared with current paranthesis ie '{'.Accordinglt false and true returns.